# Connecting MTProto Proxy to bot Telegram.Bot DLL

Tags: c#, proxy, bots, telegram

**Telegram is banned in my country and i can't connect the bot to Telegram API without a VPN 
I wanted to run the bot with *MTProto* Proxy**

**MTProtoProxy Format : host , port , secret**

My code to connect to telegram api is (with Telegram.Bot library)

```
TelegramBotClient tbc = new TelegramBotClient("TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done because **Bot API** uses https requests to communicate while MTProtoProxy proxies are meant for **MTProto API** (used by telegram clients) which is different from the Bot API.

You would need to use a normal HTTP/socks proxy in order to avoid the ban which can be found at this page https://telegrambots.github.io/book/4/proxy.html